# Java Comparable Interface compareTo method

Tags: java, interface, overloading, comparable, compareto

I don't see anything that I am doing wrong, but NetBeans gives me the following error:

```
incomparable types
required: boolean
found: java.lang.Object


public int compareTo(Object obj)  {
    if( obj instaceof Employee){
       Employee employee = (Employee) obj;
       if(this.weekly_earnings > employee.weekly_earnings)
           return 1;
       else if(this.weekly_earnings == employee.weekly_earnings)
           return 0;
       else
           return -1;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: And it doesn't return anything from the error case (should throw `ClassCastException`, actually should use generics).

Comment: I would also like to add that it would probably be better if you just returned (this.weekly_earnings - employee.weekly_earnings), saves on all the if statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's spelled `instanceof`.

Also, as Tom Hawtin mentioned in a comment, if you're using Java 1.5 or later you can write `compareTo(Employee emp)` to avoid using `instanceof` at all.  There's a thorough section on writing Comparable types in the [Object Ordering](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) Java tutorial.

Comment: Wouldn't that give a syntax-error?
Try a clean-build or restart netbeans.

Comment: @Pindatjuh: It does give the syntax error "incomparable types..."

Comment: Don't feel bad.  I wouldn't have gotten it so fast if I hadn't done it before. :)  And as Pindatjuh points out, it's not even the error message you'd expect from that typo.

Comment: This is the trick, thanks: implements Comparable<Name> => compareTo(Name n) and no need for instanceOf